# Get last nodes of DOM mutation

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, nodes, mutation-observers

I'm listening to DOM changes with DOM mutation observer like this:

```
var container = document.querySelectorAll("body")[0];

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      var target = mutation.target;
      switch (mutation.type) {

        case "childList":
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
            var lastname = node.outerHTML;
            if(typeof lastname !== "undefined")
            {


             console.log(node.outerHTML);
             //this is logging nodes as array

             var textarea = document.querySelectorAll("textarea")[0];
             textarea.value =  node.outerHTML;
             //this only gives me the very last node



            }
          });


        break;
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList : true,
    attributes : true,
    characterData : true,
    subtree : true,
    attributeOldValue : true,
    characterDataOldValue : true
  });
```

When I view the log I see an array holding all the nodes but when I try to put the nodes in a textarea only the very last one gets printed. I can change variable in `target` but that gives me all the HTML of the target while I only need the HTML of the last mutation. How do I get the nodes of the last mutation into the textarea ?

Comment: You're overwriting the `textarea.value` multiple times, so naturally it'll end up with the last write.

Comment: @cookie monster Yeah I tried solving that all day with no luck..

Comment: Ultimately, don't use `.forEach()`. Instead use `.reduce()` and assign the final value to the `textarea`. Like:  `document.querySelector("textarea").value = Array.prototype.reduce.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(str, node) { return str + (node.outerHTML || ""); }, "");`

Comment: @cookie monster Thanks will look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the value on each iteration, not adding to it. Use a variable that you add the outerHTML to, and then set the textarea value once the iteration has completed.

```
var val = '';

Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
    var lastname = node.outerHTML;
    if(typeof lastname !== "undefined") {

         val += lastname;

    }
});

document.querySelector("textarea").value = val;
```